# What are the differences between Oracle SQL clause " != ANY(...) " and " not IN (...) "

Tags: sql, oracle

I used a SQL query similar to:

```
select * from FOO_TABLE ft where ft.foo_field != any ('A','B','C');
```

I thought that the result would be all records where foo_field didn't contain 'A' or 'B' or 'C' (**exclusive**), but I obtained as result all records, also those with foo_field equal to 'A' or 'B' or 'C' .

To avoid the above issue, I used:

```
select * from FOO_TABLE ft where ft.foo_field not in ('A','B','C');
```

The above query runs as I expected.

I, often, use the following queries to generate the inverse of the queries above (to obtain all the records which contain 'A' or 'B' or 'C ' - **inclusive**):

```
select * from FOO_TABLE ft where ft.foo_field = any ('A','B','C');

select * from FOO_TABLE ft where ft.foo_field in ('A','B','C');
```

I think that's there're no result differences between the two queries I use as **inclusive**. It's that true!?

Why do the "**exclusive**" queries have different behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misusing NOT(`!`) operator.

How it works:

> "column_name = ANY (...)": The value must match one or more values in the
>   list to evaluate to TRUE.
>
> "column_name != ANY (...)": The value must not
>   match one or more values in the list to evaluate to TRUE.

In your case, your column value lets say `'A'` is matching with `=ANY('A','B','C')` but at the same time when you use `!=ANY('A','B','C')` then also it will evaluate to `TRUE` as `A!=B or A!=C`.

So you must use `column_name !=ALL('A','B','C')` or use `NOT column_name =ANY('A','B','C')` as following:

Either use

```
select * from FOO_TABLE ft where NOT ft.foo_field = any ('A','B','C'); 
 -- see the keyword NOT before column name
```

or

```
select * from FOO_TABLE ft where ft.foo_field != ALL ('A','B','C');
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Why I'm misusing the operator `!`. If I, usual, write `where foo_field != 'A'` it runs correctly? I don't understand!

Comment: In the case of ALL and ANY comparison operator they have their own concept. Please try the solution and let us know if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are equivalent, using `<> ALL` rather than `<> IN`.

When thinking about such constructs in SQL, perhaps the two most important situations to consider are:

- Empty sets (which you can only generate using subqueries).
- NULL values.

In both cases, `in` and `= any` behave the same way.  Similarly, `not in` and `<> all` behave the same way.

I should point out that `<> all` probably does not behave as expected if there are any `NULL`s in the subquery.  In this case, it returns nothing at all.  That is why I recommend `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN`.